# Lattice points in circle

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Below is statement from page #8 of Sierpinski's text 'A Selection of problems in the Theory of Numbers'.
[image]
If there were a circle with center at the midpoint of a side of any one of our squares (of lattice), then in our circle for a radius r such that $1/2 < r \le \sqrt5/2$ there would be exactly two lattice points inside such a circle.

I want to ask if given statement not wrong, as according to me there should be 6 lattice points and not two.

The reason being that the squares of lattice have a side of size $1$, and the distance between circle center and the diagonally 4 opposite sides is $\sqrt(1 + 1/4) = \sqrt5/2$. Hence, not only two adjacent lattice points at distance = 1/2, but also the diagonally 4 opposite points (at distance = $\sqrt5/2$) will also lie in the circle.

*Edit*  It seems author wants to have $\lt$ rather than $\le$, but the symbol used is clearly as stated above.

Comment: I'd say the points aren't inside the circle, if they are on the circle.

Comment: Might hinge on what is meant by "in" a circle. as in, if $(x,y)$ is "in" a circle when $x^2 + y^2 < r^2$ then it works.

Comment: Thanks for all comments for making it understandable.